# I'd like to ask how much money I have to pay for the swimming pool in the hotel

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's the context:

I have gone on a trip and am staying at a hotel. I'd like to ask how much money I have to pay for the swimming pool in the hotel.

> 1. I'd like to ask how much money it costs me to use the swimming pool.

Can I omit 'money' here?

> 2. I'd like to ask how much it is that I use the swimming pool.

I feel I can use it this way, but I'm not sure.

> 3. I'd like to ask how much money I have to pay for using the swimming pool.

I feel comfortable saying it like this.

Am I right in thinking that all of these sentences are correct?

Comment: They all say what I think you intend to convey.  I would only correct (2) to remove extraneous "*that I*" and replace it with "*to*": "how much it is *to use the swimming pool?*".  And you don't really need to say "I'd like to ask".  Just ask: "How much is it to use the swimming pool?"

Answer (score 1):

1. This sentence is okay - and yes, "money" can be (and usually is) omitted - but I would word it like this:

> I'd like to know how much it costs (for me) to use the swimming pool.

2. No. Consider this sentence:

> I'd like to ask how much it costs for me **to** use the swimming pool.

3. This sentence is almost correct; it just needs a few adjustments:

> I'd like to ask how much money I have to pay (in order) **to use** the swimming pool.